# Consecutive scp commands sometimes fail with ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: ssh, scp

*Scenario*

I use a script to copy multiple files from an EC2 linux box (ubuntu 18.04) like so (pseudo code only)

```
for file in FILES; do scp -i <key> ...; sleep 1; done
```

It will copy several dozens of files, sleeping 1 seconds after each download.

When I run it, some files get downloaded but some others return this error 
`ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`.

*Question*

1. What is causing this behavior?
2. How do I make it disappear?

Comment: what is destination host ? (raspberry ? pc ? mac ? other kind of box ?) what is medium ? (wifi ? physical link in same room ? 4G ? adsl link ? ) Your code look fine to me, you shouldn't have any error.

Comment: Why don't you call `scp` once with a list of files? Like `scp -i <key> $FILES server:/path`

Comment: @Archemar the destination host is an EC2, medium is wifi, then wire I guess :)).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks, I didn't know you could pass a list of files to scp. But what I'm curious is what's causing the issue. I know I could have just got away with it by tar all the files then download that single tar file.

Comment: I do not find it strange that a server does not like getting dozens of connections in few minutes from the same client.

Comment: I agree with @MartinPrikryl some kind of filtering/firewalling must be set on EC2 instance. either send all files in one command, or increase sleep time. you can also send 10 files in one command, sleep 5, and go for next 10 files.

Comment: Yeah, I was suspecting some kinds of limit like that from the ec2. That's what I want to know: what exactly the limit is? How do we change that limit?

Comment: If you wanted to know how to change the limit of the server, you should have told us all you need about the server from the very beginning. All your question says about the server is that is it *"linux box"*. -- And mention of *"EC2"* in a comment does not help at all either.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I modify the question to reflect your comment. Please let me know if you need more info about the server. I don't particularly change any configurations regarding `ssh` or networking on the server so they should all be default values.